# Excel Splitting a column with different types of data

Tags: microsoft-excel

an Excel split column questions for you all.

Let's say I need to split all cells in column A.

Each cell contains multiple bits of spatial data, but doesn't always contain the same value ranges. Example:

```
A1: FS13, 10-20CM
A2: 1000N, 20-30CM
A3: 1017N, LVL2, FS18, 20-30CM
```

I would need new columns for FS, N, LVL, and CM. But as you'll notice, not each cell contains all spatial data, and some cells have that information out of order relative to other cells in the column. Is there a way to split AS WELL AS sort the data into the proper order for the new columns?

If you have a formula, please also explain how to use the formula. Which cell should I use the formula in? What values in your formula do I need to replace to reflect my particular situation? Please explain the process.

Excel Office 365

Comment: so my answer did not work? https://superuser.com/questions/1488428/excel-splitting-a-column-with-different-types-of-data/1488435#1488435

Comment: How would the results appear?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirements, you can do this using `Power Query` aka `Get&Transform`

- Get the data from table/range
- Add an Index column
- Trim the text to clean things up
- Split column by delimiter (the comma) into **Rows**
- Add custom columns to separate out the TEXT and the Numeric data

  - Text data:  `=Text.Select([Column1],{"A".."Z"})`
  - Number data: `Text.Select([Column1],{"0".."9","-"})`
- Remove the original `Column 1`
- Pivot on the Header column, with Values = the Values column and select **don't aggregate** under `advanced`
- Delete the Index column

[image]

**M-Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 0, 1),
    #"Trimmed Text" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Index",{{"Column1", Text.Trim, type text}}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Trimmed Text", {{"Column1", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Column1"),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Column1", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type1", "Header", each Text.Select([Column1],{"A".."Z"})),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Values", each Text.Select([Column1],{"0".."9","-"})),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"Column1"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Columns", List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns"[Header]), "Header", "Values"),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{"Index"})
in
    #"Removed Columns1"
```

  -

To understand better what is going on, read the MS documentation on Power Query and, when you get to the PQ Editor, paste the M-Code above into the advanced editor, and examine each step individually.

**In the M-Code, you will need to replace `Table3` with the actual table name that was generated when you selected to `Get & Transform` from `table/range`**